# TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have one slider on the same page which is using jQuery version **jquery-1.7.1.min.js**, and on the same page I'm using the **Contact Form-7** and it uses **[my site url]/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1**. This both jQuery conflict with each other.

I also de-register the jQuery of **Contact Form-7**, then when I click on send button it will reload the whole page. I don't want to reload the whole page on contact form-7's button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got issue.

I think you have added hook in function.php right ?

If yes then first revert your hook. And put it as default.

And then put all jquery (included jquery) from header to footer.

Now check your issue is solve.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to turn off jQuery for Contact Form 7 in `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);
```

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-jquery-version-conflict-want-to-disable-wordpress-jquery-insertion
https://ideasilo.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/contact-form-7-1-10/

Answer (score 1):

It happens because Contact Form 7 requires wp_head and wp_footer in order to get to work properly with ajax calls. That means you probably are calling header or footer twice.

A workaround:
Don't declare the script on the header, call it through jQuery's .getScript() function when the document is fully loaded.

Example:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('path_to_script/easing_script_name.js');
});
</script>
```

The error is due to that jQuery is called before easing script it's fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

For others that have the same issue try using the [jquery.easing.compatibility.js](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.compatibility.js)
- if you don't want to have to change your easing type names - as it says on the [plugin page](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

I solved my problem this way.